# MySQL joins: how to simplyfy the given query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql="SELECT advertiser_name from broker_blocked_advertisers where pline=".$pLine." AND bid=".$cNr;
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $s=trim($row['advertiser_name']);
    $sql2= "SELECT clientid from rv_clients where clientname='{$s}'"; 
    $result2=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql2);

        while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
        $sql3= "SELECT campaignid from rv_campaigns where               clientid=".$row2['clientid']; 
        $result3=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql3);

                while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
                $sql4= "SELECT bannerid from rv_banners where campaignid=".$row3['campaignid']; 
                $result4=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql4);

                    while($row4=mysqli_fetch_array($result4)){
                    $block_adr[]= $row4['bannerid'];
                     }
                 }
          }
    }
 }
```

Anybody please suggest me to simplify the above code in a single query???.
The above code is really a wrong approach i think, please help how to short it out?.

Code description: Here i get one value from a sql table and by using that value i step forward to another query and so on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to learn about joins, a fundamental part of the SQL language.

Comment: Please provide proper DB schema , so that someone can help you.

From your question , it seems that , you want to join 4 tables , broker_blocked_advertisers,rv_clients,rv_campaigns,rv_banners.

And you need Banner IDs array, whose broker id and pline is some variable.

So please provide DB schema (tables columns name and their relation PK and FK) to get satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revised query and script:-

```
$sql = "SELECT d.bannerid 
        FROM  broker_blocked_advertisers a
        INNER JOIN rv_clients b ON a.advertiser_name = b.clientname
        INNER JOIN rv_campaigns c ON b.clientid = c.clientid
        INNER JOIN rv_banners d ON c.campaignid = d.ampaignid
        WHERE a.pline=".$pLine." AND a.bid=".$cNr;
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $block_adr[]= $row['bannerid'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the dreaded (n+1) latency death, four times over.

Every iteration through a loop is another network roundtrip.  That's going to kill your performance.

Think "join".  Bring all the data back in one round trip and sort it out on the client side.

Here's a simplified example:

```
select *
from campaign
join banner
on campaign.id = banner.campaign_id
```

That saves looping over campaigns.

Answer (score 1):

All in one query

```
$sql="SELECT 
bann.bannerid,camp.campaignid,c.clientid,b.advertiser_name as advname
from
broker_blocked_advertisers as b,
rv_clients as c,
rv_campaigns as camp,
rv_banners as bann 
where b.pline=".$pLine."
AND bid=".$cNr."
AND c.clientname=advname.advertisername
AND camp.clientid=c.clientid
AND bann.campaign_id=camp.campaig_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN USE A SINGLE QUERY LIKE THIS:

```
SELECT bannerid from rv_banners where campaignid=
(
    SELECT campaignid from rv_campaigns where clientid=
    (
         SELECT clientid from rv_clients where clientname=
         (
                SELECT advertiser_name from broker_blocked_advertisers where pline=".$pLine."
                AND bid=".$cNr;
         )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "bannerId" FROM rv_banners A, rv_campaigns B, rv_clients C, broker_blocked_advertisers  D
WHERE A.campaignid = B.campaignid AND B.clientid = C.clientname AND C.clientname = D.advertisername AND D.pline = ".$pline." AND D.bid = ".$cNr;
```